# Resized woocommerce image size but product box remains too large

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

Hello everyone and thanks in advance for your help.

Background: I am a non-programmer.

Past problem: My wordpress site theme was not optimized for woocommerce. Consequently, the image sizes of products were being expanded and blurred. So I searched here and as suggested changed .woocommerce div.product div.images img{display:block;width:48%;height:auto;box-shadow:none} to .woocommerce div.product div.images img{display:block;width:auto;height:auto;box-shadow:none}

Now my product sizes are coming out fine. However, I am still facing the problem below

**Current problem: When trying to insert products inline in post, the product box is auto expanding and becoming too large.**

See example of product page (which is fine) [here](http://chinesetranslationgroup.com/product/china-products-exhibition-book-interpreter/)
See example of bad box design when inserting the above product in page [here](http://chinesetranslationgroup.com/china-products-exhibition-interpreter/)
(you will need to scroll a little. The product has been inserted via shortcode and appears after the heading :Book interpreter today @ 125$/day only or for all 3 days @ $360 only!! Hurry before we run out of available interpreters.)

Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh I see:
you have this pre class which makes the problem. fix this:

```
pre {
display: block; //to inline or inline-block
padding: 5px 10px;
margin: 1.07142857em 0;
word-break: break-all;
word-wrap: break-word;
white-space: normal; //this is what made the problem
color: #d14;
background-color: #f7f7f9;
border: 1px solid #e1e1e8;
}
```

I think that when you used the shortcode, wordpress automatically added "pre" taglike code coz it thought this was a code. Try adding the shortcode to "text" editor without any wrapping. If not just change what I wrote in the css style

Comment: Hi Felix.. As I have written above, my product images are coming out fine. When I try to feature a product inline in my post, the product BOX size is too large. I want to change the box size.

Comment: Thank you so much Felix!!! Indeed you were right. The moment I toggled into the text editor and added the shortcode, it did it. There indeed was some kind of pre tagging going on. Thanks a ton. Really grateful.